# How to solve bottom navigation bar missing when navigate to other page in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using Flutter. I have bottom navigation with 3 tabs. When I use `Navigator.push()` to tabs 2 but the bottom navigation missing. How to solve this problem?

Here is my **tabController.dart**:

```
class _TabsControllerState extends State<TabsController> {
final List<Widget> pages = [
    HomePage(
      key: PageStorageKey('page1'),
    ),
    CartPage(
      key: PageStorageKey('page2'),
    ),
    ProfilePage(
      key: PageStorageKey('page3'),
    ),
  ];
      final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();

      var _selectedIndex = 0;

      Widget _bottomNavigationBar(var selectedIndex) => BottomNavigationBar(
        onTap: (var index) => setState(() => _selectedIndex = index),
        currentIndex: selectedIndex,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home), title: Text('Home')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.lightbulb_outline), title: Text('Cart')),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: Icon(Icons.account_circle), title: Text('Profile')),
          ],
        );

     @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return WillPopScope(
            onWillPop: ()async{
              if(_selectedIndex == 0)
              return true;
              else setState(() {
                _selectedIndex = 0;
              });
              return false;
            },
            child: Scaffold(
              bottomNavigationBar: _bottomNavigationBar(_selectedIndex),
              body: PageStorage(
                child: pages[_selectedIndex],
                bucket: bucket,
              ),
            ));
      }
    }
```

In `CartPage` I have **details page**. In Details page, when I press button I want go to `HomePage`. How can I do that?

Here is my code:

```
new FlatButton(
              child: new Text("OK"),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomePage()));
              },
            ),
```

Comment: You either need to have the bottom navigation bar replicated in each view, or you need to have it on a parent Widget/Class and only change the main view's content.

Comment: thank you for your reply, can I have example code？ I am new in flutter

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the example on the Flutter's API documentation on the `BottomNavigationBar`, [on the "Sample in App" Tab of the example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html#material.BottomNavigationBar.1), you will see that it shows you that the content that is being controlled by the `BottomNavigationBar` is declared above in the same class. You should do the same.

Remember you can simply have your Widgets in other files, import them, and instantiate them to use as each of the Tabs.

**UPDATED**

Here is an explanation of how to implement it on your code:

In your main class declare a method to change the Tab index that you can use and pass down to other classes:

```
void setTabIndex(index){
  setState((){
    _selectedIndex = index;
  });
}
```

In your CartPage class, declare a variable on the constructor for the Function type:

```
Function setTabIndex;
```

Your button would like this:

```
FlatButton(
  child: new Text("OK"),
  onPressed: () {
    setTabIndex(0);
    // 0 is the position of your HomePage in your pages List
  },
),
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, Can I have example code？ I am new in flutter

Comment: I've added the example from the documentation.

Comment: If In tab School have another details page then In detais Page I put the code navigator.push to tab business the bottom navigation will missing

Comment: With the example from documentation, there is no Navigator.push. You are not supposed to be using the Navigator at all. You just switch Widgets.

Comment: I have update my code. How can I switch Widget to replace my Navigator.push()?

Comment: I have updated my answer with parts of your code as an example of how you could fix it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210204/discussion-between-qing-and-joao-soares).

Comment: so what about the back button?

Comment: @MwBakker that depends on what you want to be the behavior of the back button. If it's to go back to the previous tab, you can wrap everything with a WillPopScope widget to override the back button behavior.